# Plot surface of constraints: Possibly via Apply or Map Reduce over a list of equations

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

I have a function `f(A,B,C)` where for specific `A` and `B` values I can use Reduce to determine the constraint on `C` for my problem using a constraint on `f`.  I want to plot the resulting surface.

To illustrate, consider

```
f = A^5 + B^3 + C^2
```

If `A` and `B` vary between 1 and 3 then I get the list of constraints (with f<20)

```
constraints = {{1, 1, C < 18}, {2, 1, C < -13}, {3, 1, C < -224}, {1, 2, C < 11}, {2, 2, C < -20}, {3, 2, C < -231}, {1, 3, C < -8}, {2, 3, C < -39}, {3, 3, C < -250}}
```

I then want to plot the surface given by

```
surf = {{1, 1, 18}, {2, 1, -13}, {3, 1, -224}, {1, 2, 
  11}, {2, 2, -20}, {3, 2, -231}, {1, 3,  -8}, {2, 3, 
   -39}, {3, 3, -250}}

ListPlot3D[surf,Mesh->All]
```

I can form the list of constraints using For loops

```
constraints = {};
For[B = 1, B <= 3, B++,
 For[A = 1, A <= 3, A++,
  f = (A)^5 + B^3 + p;
  sol  = Reduce[f < 20, p];
  constraints = Append[constraints, {A, B, sol}]
  ]
 ]
constraints
```

However I am not sure how to get from the list of constraints to the max permitted value for `C` and therefore get to the surf expression.

I also expect that For loops are not an ideal approach, and that I should be able to form lists of the `A` and `B` values and use another approach (Map, or Thread, or Apply maybe) with Reduce.  I find these methods confusing though, and don't really understand anything but the most basic examples (so possibly similar questions have not helped me figure this out).

Comment: Are `A` and `B` constrained to be integers?

Comment: No they aren't - my actual function is quite complex so this is just a simple example.  @Henrik Schumacher's solution works wonderfully, but I'd still like to know how to map across the list if anyone has a solution that works that way (just for general development of skills)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f = a^5 + b^3 + c^2
RegionPlot3D[f <= 20, {a, 1, 3}, {b, 1, 3}, {c, -5, 5}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"a", "b", "c"}]
```

[image]